# How to override properties for a specific element

Tags: css

New to CSS -- I have just added a hero image to my site. The issue is that there is a space between the image and the nav bar. In my body I have margin-top 5rem I need this for the rest of my site to function properly. How do I go about overriding it for a specific element so I can remove the blank space.

```
.hero-image{
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("/media/hero_img.jpg/");

  height: 50%;

  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  margin-top: 0;
  

body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #fafafa;
    color: #333333;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

html

```
    {% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="hero-image">
    <div class="hero-text">
        <h1>HELLO<h1>
        <button class="hero-btn">Browse</button>
    </div>
    </div>


<main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {% for post in posts %}
            <article class="media content-section">
                <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" />
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="article-metadata">
                        <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
                        <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                    </div>
                    <h3>
                        <a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.manufacture }}</a>
                        <!--Manufacture Displayed-->
                        <a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
                    </h3>
                    <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ post.image.url  }}" />
                        <!-- image Displayed-->
                    </a>
                </div>
            </article>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</main>


{% endblock content %}
```

css

```
    :root{
    --primary-color: #29b6f6;
}


body, html {
    height: 100%;
}


.hero-image{
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("/media/hero_img.jpg/");

  height: 50%;

  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  margin-top: 0;
  
  
}



.hero-text {
    vertical-align: text-top;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
}

.hero-btn{
    background: var(--primary-color);
    color: white; 
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .6em 1.3em;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    border-radius: 5em;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 1em;
}



body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #fafafa;
    color: #333333;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}



ul {
    margin: 0;
}

 
.bg-steel {
    background-color: #29b6f6;
}


.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #cbd5db;
}

    .site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
        font-weight: 500;
    }

.content-section {
    
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.article-title {
    color: #444444;
}

a.article-title:hover {
    color: #428bca;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.article-content {
    white-space: pre-line;
}

.article-img {
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.article-metadata {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3
}

    .article-metadata a:hover {
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

.article-svg {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.account-img {
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.account-heading {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

Navbar

```
<header class="site-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">HELLO</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
                <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-browse' %}">Browse</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">About</a>
                </div>
                
                <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">New Post</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                    {% else %}
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**What I have tried**

From my reading I understand that this is an issue with CSS specificity.
I tried this but it did not work. I also tried using !important but it also did not work

```
    .hero-image body{
    margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: Your trying to use the [`descendant combinator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) to select all `<body>` tags that are descendants of some element with class `.hero-image`. Are you sure `<body>` is nested inside `.hero-image`? Include the rest of your HTML and CSS!

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. It is hard to fully debug how the CSS is interacting with your HTML without the HTML. You say the issue is between the image and the nav bar, but you have given us no info about the nav bar.

Comment: _Are you sure `<body>` is nested inside `.hero-image?`_ Because it almost certainly shouldn't be, unless you are applying the `.hero-image` class to the `html` element.

Comment: Please provide a coherent rendered  *minimal* example. Don't split your HTML and CSS everywhere. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you by providing enough to demonstrate the problem, but not giving us stuff that no relation to the problem. Ideally, for us, there should be no assembly required. You still haven't shown where the navbar sits in relation to the hero image